# Integral of partial derivative: $\int_0^\mu \frac{\partial q} {\partial u}\,du$

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

An equation (borrowed from statistics QLE) is

$$ \frac{\partial q(\mu,y)} {\partial\mu}=
\dfrac{y-\mu}{a_i \phi V(\mu)}$$

Apparently this is equivalent to

$$q(\mu,y)=\int_0^\mu \frac{y-u}{a_i \phi V(u)}\,du + \textrm{a function of }y.$$

I'm not 100% sure how they got this equation. It seems like they computed

$$\int_0^\mu \frac{\partial q(u,y)} {\partial u}\,du =
q(\mu,y) + \textrm{a function of }y$$

from the LHS. Instinctively, I try to evaluate this integral by cancelling the differentials of $u$, but I'm not sure that is allowed because one is a $d$ and one is a $\partial$, and even then the integral would turn into (I believe) $\int_0^\mu \partial q=\mu$, which does not give the equivalent statement. Can someone help clear up my confusion? Thanks!

Comment: It may help people answer if you include a source for these equations or define the functions more clearly

Comment: @HenryLee I don't believe that the functions/variables have any further constraints, but the first equation is the definition of the Quasi-Likelihood Estimator $q$. The source for the first and second equations were lecture notes by Tengyao Wang for a course at Cambridge University. Wang left this year for UCL and took his webpage down a few weeks ago, so I'm not sure if they're available online somewhere

Comment: Sorry: $q$ is the Quasi-Likelihood Function, whose maximizer is the QLE.

Comment: For the answer/solution, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191725/